# How do I open Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have installed Ubuntu on the same drive as Windows 7. When I try to open Ubuntu I get a message "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is alraedy installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel."
How do I do this?

Comment: I wonder **how** you try to "open Ubuntu" from within Windows...

Comment: How do you "open Ubuntu"? To me, it sounds like you just tried to open a .iso file in Windows. If that's the case, please refer to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Sounds like you're just double clicking on the file directly from windows. To use Ubuntu you need to [install it first](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

Comment: Question like this make me smile, because they remind me of my early computing days when I tried similar things :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start Ubuntu at the same time while you're using Windows. You have to choose Ubuntu before entering Windows at the start of your computer.

Press any key at the three-second countdown when you boot your computer. There you must see the options 'Windows' and 'Ubuntu'. Choose Ubuntu.

Also see the link for details: http://www.ehow.com/how_6545352_dual-boot-ubuntu.html

Comment: To expand Windows does not ever see the Drive Ubuntu uses.